# Convergence of $\sum |a_{n+1}-a_{n}|$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a Cauchy sequence. 
>
>  If $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is monotonic then $\sum |a_{n+1}-a_{n}|$ converges.

I know that this argument is true since, 
$\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \space, n>1: a_n = a_1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (a_{k+1}-a_{k}) = a_1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} |a_{k+1}-a_{k}|$

By the monotonicity of $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$.

However my struggle is to understand if this argument holds without the assumption that $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is monotonic. 
Naively, I would expect the series to converge without the assumption.

I'd like to have some ideas so I can improve my intuition in such cases, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even with the convergence of the $(a_n)$, you're in for a bad time: let
$$(a_1,a_2,a_3,...) = (1/2,-1/2, 1/3,-1/3,1/4,-1/4,...).$$
The series in the question immediately diverges by the comparison test, i.e.,  $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n - a_{n-1}| \geq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} = \infty.$$

Answer (score 2):

Consider the sequence $0,1,0,\frac{1}{2},0,\frac{1}{3},0,\frac{1}{4},\cdots$